# iOS: How to notify the appDelegate from a UIViewController

Tags: ios

Simple question about how to pass information in my iOS application.

The appDelegate has a variable myVar.

I have a UIViewController with a View with a switcher. When the switcher switches, I need to set another value to myVar.

Since UIViewController is not supposed to know the interface of appDelegate, how can I notify it about the switch and update its variable ?

NB. If you are going to answer "just send a message", please let me know how to implement it as well, since it is not clear.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW1
Can you do similar to keyboard notifications ?

Idea is to implement custom Switch which sends notifications to all registered listeners; register what ever object you think should receive notifications.

Comment: @KKK4SO So, should I go for notifications and listeners ? Anybody can suggest me the APIs to use for it ? I just want to know what's the common way to do this stuff, without breaking the OO design

Comment: The link i provided can give you an overall understanding of how notifications work (when SIP is shown/Hidden). Some thing similar can be implemented for your custom Control. Tell me if there is some thing specific that you are not clear with this approach

Comment: @KKK4SO I see. Well, I'm actually reading the Notifications chapter now, and I've seen there are some specific notification classes, so I guess I'm going to use them. Still, I was wondering if there is a delegate for this kind of stuff (user interface events).

Comment: (So that I can use the delegate instead of implementing my own notifications

Comment: AFAIK, no default notifications for custom controls. I doubt if there are any, even for default UIControls (other than textfeild and textview). I believe you are on course to do it with a proper OO design in Cocoa way :)

Comment: @KKK4SO this page shows all communication mechanisms... http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW7

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can send a message. You'll get a warning about it, but it will work.

After finding out you don't need app-wide state, `NSNotification`s are a good way to go here.

Comment: THis is exactly why I posted this question. I want the best OO design choice. Invoking a method of appDelegate is not good,  I guess.

Comment: I also ponder the best choice for app-wide state. I have used singleton objects for this in the past, but some people, perhaps rightly, frown on this.

Comment: Well, I don't necessarily need an app-wide state. I have 2 UIViewControllers and the second one is initialized in the first one. When a switch switches in the second one's view, then the first UIViewController should be informed.

Comment: So, the firstViewController knows about the second one. But not viceversa. I don't is good to reference the first one from the secondViewController.